# Plot InfluxDB moving average in Grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana, moving-average, codahale-metrics

In my influxdb i have the metrics like below. These metrics are dropwizard meter metrics which capture the moving average values for 1-, 5-, and 15-minute.

```
select * from "messages" limit 10   

time                client             cluster count  fifteen-minute     five-minute        mean-minute        module                  one-minute         server
----                ------             ------- -----  --------------     -----------        -----------        ------                  ----------         ------
1507335739883000000 OurImportantClient CL01    0      0                  0                  0                  messageprocessor 0                       localhost
1507335749886000000 OurImportantClient CL01    501    0.5520477628396372 1.6287864046290808 25.041124895717168 messageprocessor 7.3709815118186555      localhost
1507335759884000000 OurImportantClient CL01    587    0.6412384642848744 1.859679429071625  19.562294999745585 messageprocessor 7.614637212636722       localhost
1507335769881000000 OurImportantClient CL01    30475  33.662903467742275 99.87494091791048  761.8030767050573  messageprocessor 467.97943323340695      localhost
1507335779884000000 OurImportantClient CL01    62362  68.51470940480358  201.11411048844886 1247.0948280106677 messageprocessor 885.6986695814577       localhost
1507335789882000000 OurImportantClient CL01    94824  103.63811321618489 301.02408263969613 1580.2875055219413 messageprocessor 1249.7709883284872      localhost
1507335799881000000 OurImportantClient CL01    132473 144.09666119665695 414.58418058144684 1892.3728563562054 messageprocessor 1635.661065015788       localhost
1507335809881000000 OurImportantClient CL01    171835 185.9911221266662  530.0218087595953  2147.790629620081  messageprocessor 1988.92207608162        localhost
1507335819880000000 OurImportantClient CL01    215110 231.75939527511298 654.5929160902938  2389.999838003209  messageprocessor 2349.874824492088       localhost
1507335829881000000 OurImportantClient CL01    273217 293.4094925023778  823.6482709833962  2732.078610331237  messageprocessor 2881.3518546121827      localhost
```

How to plot these moving averages in Grafana dashboard ?

Comment: What have you tried? The standard query builder in grafana should be able to pick these up.